# How can I get quantity with SP API Python

Tags: python, amazon-selling-partner-api

I need a product's unit of stock(quantity). Is it possible with SP API, if possible how can I get it?

Note: I can get it with SKU like the following code but the product is **not listed** by my sellers.

```
from sp_api.api import Inventories
quantity = Inventories(credentials=credentials, marketplace=Marketplaces.FR).get_inventory_summary_marketplace(**{
        "details": False,
        "marketplaceIds": ["A13V1IB3VIYZZH"],
        "sellerSkus": ["MY_SKU_1" , "MY_SKU_2"]
})
print(quantity)
```

Answer (score 0):

from sp_api.api import Inventories
quantity = Inventories(credentials=credentials, marketplace=Marketplaces.FR).get_inventory_summary_marketplace(**{
"details": False,
"marketplaceIds": ["A13V1IB3VIYZZH"],
"sellerSkus": ["MY_SKU_1" , "MY_SKU_2"]
})
print(quantity)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).